# Access a cloud database from magento website Cpanel

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, mysql-workbench, cpanel

I have a database on Amazon web service. I can access it from mySql workbench.
Now I want to connect that database from my website Cpanel(which is another host server). Can you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Connect to the right endpoint?

Comment: sorry? can you please clarify?

Comment: You can access the database using mySql workbench. The connection information you used should give you a clue how to connect from an other location.

Comment: I have already accessed it from workbench but not able to access it from magento website

Comment: Something like [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/mysql_remote.html)?

Comment: What data did you use to connect with MySQL Workbench? Server name, port, username, password... Whatever you used, put it in Magento.

Comment: How did you connect Workbench to Cpanel MySQL. I am struggling with it